# Applications of the simplex $2$-category and its higher dimensional cousins

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories

The [simplex category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category) $\Delta$ has a $2$-category refinement $\Delta_2$ given by the full sub-$2$-category of the $2$-category $\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by the ordinal categories $$, $$, $:=\star$, $:=\star$ $\ldots$. One fun fact about it is that the coface and codegeneracy maps in this $2$-category now form an adjoint string:
$$\mathrm{d}_0\vdash\mathrm{s}_0\vdash\mathrm{d}_1 \vdash \dots \vdash\mathrm{d}_{n-1}\vdash \mathrm{s}_{n-1} \vdash\mathrm{d}_n.$$
I've seen this extra structure only used two times, namely:

- [A categorified Dold-Kan correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08356); (see also the nCatCafé discussion [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/10/categorification_and_the_cosmi.html))
- [On cofinal functors of $\infty$-bicategories](https://d-nb.info/1264307314/34).

(Also worth of note is the following fact, [noted](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2017/10/categorification_and_the_cosmi.html#c052895) in the nCatCafé discussion linked above: If the simplicial nerve of a $2$-monad $T$ extends to a $2$-simplicial nerve, then $T$ is lax-idempotent.)

**Question 1.** Other than these, what are some other applications/structures which use the $2$-category structure of $\Delta_2$?

**Question 2.** It seems to me that $\Delta_2$ is built by means of the following procedure, specialised to $k=2$:

- First we take Street's [orientals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oriental) and ask that every $n$-cell with $n\geq k$ is an identity;
- Then we consider the full subcategory of $(k-1)\text{-}\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by the $(k-1)$-categories corresponding to these "truncated orientals".

Repeating this procedure for $n\geq3$ should give a simplex $3$-category $\Delta_3$, a simplex $4$-category $\Delta_4$, and so on. For example, the $2$-categories $_2$, $_2$, $_2$, $\ldots$ used to build $\Delta_3$ look just like the $n$-simplices in the Duskin nerve of a $2$-category, pictured in detail [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+nerve+of+a+bicategory#picturing_the_duskin_nerve).

> **Aside I.** A more conceptual way to build $\Delta_3$ and its higher dimensional cousins is by using lax joins:
>
> - $\Delta$ is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by $$, $$, and the iterated joins $:=\star$, $:=\star\star$,
> - $\Delta_2$ is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{2Cat}$ spanned by $$, $$, and the iterated *lax* joins
>   $_2:=\star^{\mathrm{lax}}$,
>   $_2:=\star^{\mathrm{lax}}\star^{\mathrm{lax}}$.
>
> There are also oplax and pseudo versions of this construction, so we
> should really be speaking of a "lax simplex $3$-category". More
> generally, there will be $3^{n-1}$ variants of "the simplex
> $n$-category", just like there are $3^{n-1}$ variants of the join of
> $n$-categories.¹ Horrifying!
>
> **Aside II.** Being a strict $n$-category, $\Delta_n$ also has an underlying $(n-1)$-category $\Delta_{n|1}$ (e.g. $\Delta_{2|1}$ is the
> usual simplex category). It seems to me that $\Delta_{3|1}$ is
> something close to (but not quite, I think) the lax morphism
> classifier $\mathsf{L}\Delta_2$ of the simplex $2$-category, for which
> we have a bijection $$\{\text{$2$-functors
>   $\mathsf{L}\Delta_2\to\mathcal{C}$}\}\cong\{\text{Lax functors
>   $\Delta_{2}\to\mathcal{C}$}\}.$$
>
> **Aside III.** There are actually lax, oplax, and pseudo variants of the simplex $1$-category too: the lax variant is the usual simplex
> category, the oplax variant is isomorphic to the lax variant, and the
> pseudo variant is the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by
> the localisations of the ordinal categories at every morphism.
>
> Alternatively, we may also construct the pseudo variant as the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by the "iso-ordinal" categories, defined iteratively starting from $$ by means of the "isojoin" of categories, defined in the same way as the join $\mathcal{C}\star\mathcal{D}$ but
> where we replace the morphisms from the objects of $\mathcal{C}$ to
> those of $\mathcal{D}$ in $\mathcal{C}\star\mathcal{D}$ by
> isomorphisms.
>
> And it turns out that the resulting category is already very well-known: it is a skeleton of the category of
> finite sets, and presheaves on it are [symmetric (simplicial)
> sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+set), which form
> another model for $\infty$-groupoids.

**Question 2 stated, finally.** Have these simplex $n$-categories been considered before in the literature (or by someone reading this post)? What would be some applications of them?

---

¹There's a similar phenomenon in the cubical word:

- The "cube $2$-category" may be defined as the full subcategory of $\mathsf{Cat}$ spanned by $$, $$, $\times$, $\times\times$, $\ldots$: instead of iterated joins, this time we use iterated products.
- The "cube $3$-category" is then defined as the full subcategory of $\mathsf{2Cat}$ spanned by $$, $$, $\otimes_{\mathrm{Gray}}$, $\otimes_{\mathrm{Gray}}\otimes_{\mathrm{Gray}}$, $\ldots$, where this time we throw away the Cartesian product and use the Gray tensor product.

As with the simplicial case, there will be $3^{n-1}$ variants of "the cube $n$-category", just like there are $3^{n-1}$ variants of the Gray tensor product of $n$-categories. Also horrifying!

Comment: $\Delta$ with its concatenation product is the free monoidal category generated by a monoid. I believe $\Delta_2$ is the free monoidal 2-category generated by a lax idempotent monoid  (In the sense of https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax-idempotent+2-monad )

Comment: @SimonHenry That would be a nice universal property! (By the way, I hope I'm not being too pedantic here, but should $\Delta$ be $\Delta_+$ instead, the augmented simplex category?)

Comment: Oh yes absolutely sorry - you need the empty ordinal for both of these.

Comment: Pursuant to @SimonHenry 's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436142/applications-of-the-simplex-2-category-and-its-higher-dimensional-cousins#comment1123674_436142), I wonder if there are also higher-dimensional analogs of the notion of a lax-idempotent _adjunction_?